# Deployer keeps creating "pubXX"-folders

Tags: content-delivery

I'm trying to configure the deployer to publish a publication I have ported from Tridion 2013 to SDL Web 8. At first, the deployer published to the file system root (defined as defaultFile in *cd_storage_conf.xml*) + publication path (defined in the CME). That was exactly what I wanted. But: After messing around with the config to solve [my previous issue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/sdl-web-8-cant-resolve-dcp-using-in-process-api), i have ran into a new problem:

When publishing, the deployer now creates a new folder in the file system root, called pub*XX* (where *XX* is the publication ID), where it then puts the folder structure I previously had, inside.

**Does anyone know what I have done wrong?**

This is a relevant excerpt of my current cd_storage_conf (in the deployer folder):

```
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="${broker_staging_hostname}" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="${broker_staging_port}" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="${broker_staging_db}" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="${broker_staging_username}" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="${broker_staging_password}" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile"
                 defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
            <Root Path="/progs/portals/staging/" />
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile"
                 defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
            <Root Path="/progs/portals/staging/.dynamic" />
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="tnprivatDataFile"
                 defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
            <Root Path="/progs/portals/staging/tnprivat/web/.dynamic" />
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="tnprivatFile"
                 defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
            <Root Path="/progs/portals/staging/tnprivat/web/binaries" />
        </Storage>
    </Storages>
</Global>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultDataFile" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Query" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="XSLT" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" cached="true" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" cached="true" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="defaultdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Page" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile"/>

    <Publication Id="106" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

    </Publication>
    <Publication Id="107" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

    </Publication>
    <Publication Id="110" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

    </Publication>
    <Publication Id="52" cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
       <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" cached="true" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="tnprivatDataFile"/>
       <Item typeMapping="Page" storageId="defaultFile"/>
       <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    </Publication>
</ItemTypes>
<License Location="${cd_license_location}"/>`
```

The log files aren't telling me much at all. In cd_core I see a recurring error:

`2016-10-03 12:32:13,797 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Transaction (Process ID 847) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
2016-10-03 12:32:13,798 WARN  PreCommitPhase - Unable to store item inside current transaction: Unable to remove data entity
2016-10-03 12:32:13,798 WARN  PreCommitPhase - Failed to Prepare: tcm:0-708030-66560 error: Unable to store item inside current transaction
2016-10-03 12:32:13,801 WARN  DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failure message: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-708030-66560 for transaction: tcm:0-708030-66560
2016-10-03 12:34:35,108 WARN  DeployerConfigurationLoader - New configuration is not found.
2016-10-03 12:36:38,505 WARN  DeployerConfigurationLoader - New configuration is not found.`

But I don't see the relevance.

At one point I saw this error:

`2016-10-03 12:19:26,812 WARN  FSPublicationDAO - PublicationDAO is set to File System, which is not supported. Check your bindings settings and/or license file or remove PublicationDeploy module from deployer configuration.`

Which seems pretty relevant, but I set the defaultStorageId of my publications to defaultdb, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

As outlined in [the online documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-78E44D6E-1D22-432B-B2BB-0A3650FF36AE):

> If your license for database storage is expired or missing, you can configure Content Delivery to store content on the file system as a fallback scenario.

This is done by setting the `defaultFilesystem` attribute to `true` to one of your filesystem storage configurations

This results in DCPs being stored in a locations such as: **C:\progs\portals\staging\pub107\dcp\jsp**

Where:

- `C:\progs\portals\staging\` is the `Path` setting of the default storage item
- `107` is the Id of the Publication being published from, and
- `jsp` is the extension of that particular DCP

Therefore, if you're seeing this type of folder being created, you may want to check your Deployer's license file and the connection to the database.

---

P.S. You may also want to checkout [Daniel Neagu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236156/daniel-neagu)'s answer to the following question over on Stack Overflow:
[how to set publish dcp for child or other publications to different location without overiding all other settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519810/how-to-set-publish-dcp-for-child-or-other-publications-to-different-location-wit)

---

**Update (following Morten's comment) which is too long to add as a comment:**

I would expect the priority ordering for where to store DCPs to be from most specific to least specific. I.e:

1. A Publication-specific `typeMapping` for `ComponentPresentation` with an extension
2. A default `itemMapping` for `ComponentPresentation` with an extension
3. A Publication-specific `itemMapping` for `ComponentPresentation` (without an extension)
4. A default `itemMapping`  for `ComponentPresentation` (without an extension)
5. A Publication-specific `defaultStorageId` (if no `itemMapping` for `ComponentPresentation` is specified)
6. a generic `defaultStorageId` (if no `itemMapping` for `ComponentPresentation` is specified and no Publication-specific element defined).

However, someone with knowledge of the inner workings of the Deployer code may know better.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, Jonathan. Setting defaultFilesystem to false solved the issue. There was not a problem with the license file or connection to the database, though. 

From my understanding, defaultFilesystem should be a fallback if you have configured a filesystem storage definition without a storageID. But now it seems like setting one of these to true will trigger this behavior (pubXX) regardless of more specific configurations. Is this a bug, or simply me misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: Glad that it helped. As you say, I I would expect the priority ordering to be from most specific to least specific. I've updated my answer above with this.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I would appreciate it if anyone with detailed knowledge on the deployer could have a look into it. I have the same understanding of the prioritities as you do, but the deployer does not fully exhibit this behavior. Also, the issue applied to everything, including pages and binaries.